# Convert compile-time constant vector to heap-allocated version

Tags: c++, c++17, visual-studio-2019, heap-memory

I made Visual Studio's Code Analyzer mad. This line:

```
void Foo() {
    const std::vector<uint8_t> bar{ /* 21,140 uint8_t entries */ };
    //...
}
```

emits a [C6262 warning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/code-quality/c6262?view=vs-2019):

```
Function uses 21140 bytes of stack: exceeds /analyze:stacksize`16384`. Consider moving some data to heap
```

The vector contains the individual bytes of a binary file. My whole intention in this case is to not use external files so the data is always available to the function caller.

**Is there an easy way to convert the the compile-time value to a heap-allocated one?**

Moving the declaration out of the function into static file-level scope is prohibitively expensive and time-consuming because A) the memory will never be released, and B) this is just one of about a dozen functions that use multiple large binary arrays like this and renaming them all doesn't scale well.

Ignoring the warning is also out of the question.

EDIT:

MCRE as requested. ("CR" is debatable because it's part of a 300,000 LOC game engine, but that shouldn't matter as the CA fails at the basic declaration of a too-large vector...so here's the actual usage instead.) As stated in the comments of [ShadowRanger's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62206155/421178), neither declaring the large vectors as `static` nor `const static` fixes the problem and the CA still emits the warning:

```cpp
std::unique_ptr<ShaderProgram> Renderer::CreateDefaultShaderProgram() noexcept {
    static std::vector<uint8_t> g_VertexFunction{ /* 5K entries */ };
    static std::vector<uint8_t> g_DefaultPixelFunction{ /* 21,140 entries */ };
    // /\/\ Code Analysis warns here at g_DefaultPixelFunction declaration.

    ShaderProgramDesc desc{};
    desc.name = "__default";
    desc.device = _rhi_device.get();
    {
        ID3D11VertexShader* vs = nullptr;
        _rhi_device->GetDxDevice()->CreateVertexShader(g_VertexFunction.data(), g_VertexFunction.size(), nullptr, &vs);

        ID3DBlob* blob = nullptr;
        ::D3DCreateBlob(g_VertexFunction.size(), &blob);
        std::memcpy(blob->GetBufferPointer(), g_VertexFunction.data(), g_VertexFunction.size());

        g_VertexFunction.clear();
        g_VertexFunction.shrink_to_fit();

        desc.vs = vs;
        desc.vs_bytecode = blob;
        desc.input_layout = _rhi_device->CreateInputLayoutFromByteCode(blob);
    }
    {
        ID3D11PixelShader* ps = nullptr;
        _rhi_device->GetDxDevice()->CreatePixelShader(g_DefaultPixelFunction.data(), g_DefaultPixelFunction.size(), nullptr, &ps);

        ID3DBlob* blob = nullptr;
        ::D3DCreateBlob(g_DefaultPixelFunction.size(), &blob);
        std::memcpy(blob->GetBufferPointer(), g_DefaultPixelFunction.data(), g_DefaultPixelFunction.size());

        g_DefaultPixelFunction.clear();
        g_DefaultPixelFunction.shrink_to_fit();

        desc.ps = ps;
        desc.ps_bytecode = blob;
    }
    return std::make_unique<ShaderProgram>(std::move(desc));
}
```

EDIT 2:

As per [Jeff Garrett's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62207299/421178), the solution is to declare an initializer list variable beforehand as static (const because "Const all the Things!"):

```cpp
const static std::initializer_list<uint8_t> vs_init_list{/*5K entries*/};
std::vector<uint8_t> g_VertexFunction{vs_init_list};

const static std::initializer_list<uint8_t> ps_init_list{/*21K entries*/};
std::vector<uint8_t> g_PixelFunction{ps_init_list};

//... Same as before
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The stack space for a vector does not depend on its size.

The vector is being initialized with a std::initializer_list. That is what requires potential stack space. That is what you could make static.

Comment: Though, now that I think about it, would it still incur any extra memory? The [initializer list specification](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list) says it is constructed using temporary memory but there's no mention (that I can find) of a statically declared one.

Comment: An initializer_list is a pointer to an implicit array of constant elements which lives as long as the list. There is no restriction that it cannot be static.

Comment: Regarding memory, first of all, compilers should optimize these things: I wouldn't expect a compiler to copy from rodata to the local stack to initialize the vector in your initial program, and making it static could make it harder for the compiler to make this optimization. Using a vector<> for this also will probably require at least a copy from rodata to the vector<>. The cheapest memory option will be a C array of constant elements or a std::array<> which is a thin wrapper around a C array.

Answer (score 3):

If you leave them where they are and declare them `static` as well as `const` it wouldn't require renaming; `static` doesn't require moving to file scope (which would risk name collisions), you'd only move to file scope if you needed to share it among multiple functions.

The memory usage shouldn't be an issue; the initializer would have to be stored in the program in some way anyway, so storing it in `static` scope isn't an issue (it might even reduce effective program memory usage by replacing runtime allocation and initialization with reading from the mmap-ed binary file constants).

Comment: Ended up declaring it as plain `static`. Later in the function I'm copying the data into a different-but-permanent buffer and I don't want to have unnecessary duplicates. That allowed me to `clear()` and `shrink_to_fit()` the temporary function-level buffers so they go away.

Comment: ....Annnd neither solution works. :/ Same warning with both `static` and `const static`

Comment: @Casey: That is... strange. A `static const` anything should be allocated and initialized exactly once, which shouldn't involve any stack usage at all. You need to post a [MCVE] that can reproduce the problem on its own, because I don't see how a `static` would involve *any* stack usage.

Comment: Clarified question with real-world usage.

Comment: @Casey One likely problem with `static` is that the data still needs to go into the stack for the vector's constructor function. Ideally, you would use a `static` variable that can be initialized in-place, like a `std::array`. When you import the binary data into your source code, do you know how many bytes there are? Could you use that to generate an appropriate type along the lines of `std::array<uint8_t, 21140>`?

Answer (score 2):

See if this helps any.  It won't move the data to the heap, but it will put it in static data which needs no runtime at all to initialize.

```
void Foo() {
    const uint8_t std::bar [] = { /* 21,140 uint8_t entries */ };
    //...
}
```

Comment: I prefer `std::vector` or `std::array` because they know their size.

Comment: @Casey Isn't static array's size can be known?

Comment: @Casey:  The array size can be found from the compile-time expression (thus a const) of `sizeof (std::bar)/sizeof(bar[0])`.